# Logical AND in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

Let's say my XPath yields 20 HTML h3 elements. I have two requirements that need to be met:

1. I need to start from the second `<h3>` element, AND
2. I only want to capture up to 10 `<h3>` elements.

In order to accomplish this first part, I used this

```
h3[position() > 1]
```

However, that leaves me with elements 2-20. Can I add a boolean operator in there to make something like

```
h3[position() > 1 && position() < 10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, except use `and` rather than `&&`:

```
h3[position() > 1 and position() < 10]
```

Also, if you want the first ten `h3` elements starting with the second one, it should be:

```
h3[position() > 1 and position() < 12]
```

Comment: Well, `&&` is logical 'and' in `C`, `Java`, etc, but `&` precedes entity references in XML, so `and` was definitely a better fit for XPath.

Answer (score 0):

If you want up to ten elements, the correct code is `h3[position() > 1 and position() <= 11]`.